# can we show geometries that are out of canvas (3D space) in three.js

Tags: three.js

I am creating one geometry at location (0,0,0) but projecting at some other location (for ex. @50,50,50). If the point (0,0,0) is going out of canvas, then geometry is hiding.

Is there any way to always render it on canvas?

Comment: Check [frustumCulled](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D) property of an object.

Comment: I dont think it is serving my purpose. Sorry buddy.

 I have projected it through shader.

Comment: I dont think it is serving my purpose.

I have projected it through shader programming. to different location but once original location going out of context.

Answer (score 0):

How far off the edge does the origin need to be?

You could make the canvas larger than you need, than mask the areas on the edge such that only the center area shows. That way when the origin goes off the side, it will still technically be on the canvas, and the projected geometry will be in the visible area.  I expect you will only need a buffer space equal to projection offset.

See here for an example of applying a mask: https://jsfiddle.net/shawnoakley/n1368qr0/2/

Example code:

```
var context = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');

// Mask color
context.fillStyle = '#000';
// Image proportions
context.fillRect(0,0,600,400);

var unmaskedImage = function(x, y, radius){
    context.save();
    context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    context.fill();
    context.restore();
};


unmaskedImage(300, 300, 300);
```